# AVaudio Player Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using Avaudio player in our app.I play the song from list after playing when i back to list for selecting another song then fist one is also playing.

I want to stop previous song and then play the other song.

Please help me.

Comment: please go back over your previous answers and accept the best ones...its the way this site works and you will get more help that way.

Answer (score 0):

`[oldplayer stop];`

`[newplayer start];`

you may also be able to get this behavior by setting your audio session up correctly: say

`UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;   // Defines a new variable of type UInt32 and initializes it with the identifier 
                                                                        // for the category you want to apply to the audio session.
        AudioSessionSetProperty (
            kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,                        // The identifier, or key, for the audio session property you want to set.
            sizeof(sessionCategory),                                    // The size, in bytes, of the property value that you are applying.
            &sessionCategory                                            // The category you want to apply to the audio session.
        );`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're creating another AVAudioPlayer instance. Let's say the old one is called "audioPlayer"; you need to stop it using audioPlayer.stop() and then create a  new audioPlayer using audioPlayer = new AVAudioPlayer(...)
This will ensure that ARC deallocates the old instance of AVAudioPlayer, so it no longer exists.